# SQL join combined with new column calculation

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables in SQL that look like this:

Table 1:

```
ID    TaxYear    Earnings
01       2000        2234
01       2001         123
02       2004       12344
02       2006         234
02       2007           0
02       2008         123
```

Table 2:

```
ID    JobEnd
01      1998
02      2000
02      2007
```

I need to combine these tables to make a new column giving the number of years between TaxYear and JobEnd. However, I need this value to reset every time TaxYear passes a new JobEnd year. So my final table would look like this:

```
ID    TaxYear    Earnings    YearsSinceJobEnd
01       2000        2234                   2
01       2001         123                   3
02       2004       12344                   4
02       2006         234                   6
02       2007           0                   7
02       2008         123                   1
```

For ID 02, when YearsSinceJobEnd is calculated as TaxYear minus 2000, up until TaxYear passes the new JobEnd year of 2007, when it is subsequently calculated as TaxYear minus 2007.

I'm getting very confused about how to do this. If I join the tables I end up with multiple columns per TaxYear, which I need to avoid. But I can't think how to calculate the new column without joining them.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Show us your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can user `CROSS APPLY` to find the required `JobEnd` for each ID

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.TaxYear, t1.Earnings,
       YearsSinceJobEnd = t1.TaxYear - e.JobEnd
FROM   Table1 t1
       CROSS APPLY
       (
           SELECT JobEnd = MAX(t2.JobEnd)
           FROM   Table2 t2
           WHERE  t2.ID = t1.ID
           AND    t2.JobEnd < t1.TaxYear
       ) e
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `datediff()` with [DATETIMEFROMPARTS ()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetimefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
select t1.id, t1.TaxYear, t1.Earnings, 
       datediff(year, DATEFROMPARTS(t2.JobEnd, 1, 1), DATEFROMPARTS(t1.TaxYear, 1, 1)) as YearsSinceJobEnd
from t1 inner join
     t2
     on t2.id = t1.id;
```

If you don't want `JOIN` then use `APPLY` :

```
select t1.id, t1.TaxYear, t1.Earnings,
       datediff(year, DATEFROMPARTS(t2.JobEnd, 1, 1), DATEFROMPARTS(t1.TaxYear, 1, 1)) as YearsSinceJobEnd  
from t1 cross apply
     ( select top (1) t2.JobEnd 
       from t2
       where t2.id = t1.id and t2.JobEnd < t1.TaxYear
       order by t2.JobEnd desc
     ) t2;
```